# Open Excel File in C# and invoke add-ins command

Tags: c#, .net, excel, .net-core, excel-addins

I want to loop through a list of excel files and for each excel file I need to programmatically invoke an add-in action and log the result!

[image]

Any suggestions on how I can achieve that?

Thank you

Comment: Addins run only inside Excel, which means you have to use Excel interop to start Excel, load the file and execute the addin

Comment: Thanks,@panagiotis-kanavos  Can you please provide an example?